# How to install `vim-scripts/LanguageTool` using Vundle?

Tags: vim, installation, vim-plugin, vundle

I am installing the [`vim-scripts/LanguageTool`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LanguageTool) plugin using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim):

1. Put `Plugin 'vim-scripts/LanguageTool'` in `.vimrc`;
2. Run `:PluginInstall` in a vim file (and `Vundle` says "Done").

However, when I run `:LanguageToolCheck`, I got the following error:

> LanuageTool cannot be found at: /home/MY-USE-NAME/languagetool-2.4.1/languagetool-commandline.jar.
>   You need to install LanguageTool and/or set up g:languagetool_jar
>   to indicate the location of the languagetool-commandline.jar file.

What should I do? Thanks.

---

The [Docs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3223) installs the LanguageTool plugin as follows:

```
$ mkdir ~/.vim 
$ cd ~/.vim 
$ unzip /path-to/LanguageTool.zip 
$ vim -c 'helptags ~/.vim/doc'
```

---

***Solution:***

According to [Docs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3223), this plugin needs a standalone [LanguageTool for desktop](https://www.languagetool.org/) which includes the required `languagetool_commandline.jar`. Install it and set `g:languagetool_jar` according to the answer below.

Comment: Did you set the `g:languagetool_jar` to the path of the languagetool jar file ?

Comment: @Nobe4 No. I don't know how to do that. I am quite new to vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to link the path to the `langagetool` within vim, so it can find it and use it.

In vim you can define/set variables with the following command:

```
let g:languagetool_jar="/path/to/the/file.jar"
```

The `g:` means that the variable is global and thus accessible from every script/plugin. In that case, it means that the `LanguageTool` will know where to find the jar file.

Have a look at [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/19.html) and [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/20.html) for more information.

Comment: Using arch, I installed `languagetool` from the package manager `pacman`. I know where the binary is, but cannot find the file `languagetool_commandline.jar`.

Comment: You can use `pacman -Ql languagetool | grep commandline` to find the jar. I ran into an [issue](https://github.com/dpelle/vim-LanguageTool/issues/22) with vim-language that made me switch to [vim-grammarous](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-grammarous) that also integrates LanguageTool into Vim and Neovim.